Why does R return values from a dataframe's column not being called by its entire column name?
This is probably a "smart" solution that, after more than 8 years of working almost every day with R, I hadn't noticed before (nor found documentation). Why does R return values from a dataframe's column not being called by its entire column name?
df <- data.frame(Abcd = 1, About = 2, This = 3)
# All the following are TRUE
df$This == df$T
df$Abc == df$Abcd
is.null(df$A)
!is.null(df$T)

IMO, quite funny and could be problematic if users are unaware of this intended behavior.
In summary: R will return a column's values if no other column contains the initial string written. Are there other similar behaviors in base R like this?

Yes, it is a feature, not a bug. If the short name matches more than one column, it will not work, it only works when it matches partially exactly one name.

Partial match is documented in ?base::Extract.
